# Display number of matching search options on Textfield input in Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize the Material UI Autocomplete and show a count of options that are currently shown in a Popper menu after a user searches and enters a string in the search box (this is before you select an option and it becomes a `value` which is easy to get a count of with `value.length`). I may be missing the prop in order to grab the number of options *showing* out of the entire option array when a user enters a keystroke in the `<Textfield/>` of the `renderInput` prop in the `<Autocomplete/>`.

Here is the code:

```
 <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        renderInput={params => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="underlined"
              placeholder="Search"
            />
            <span className={classes.visibleFilterNum}>
              Showing X of {options.length}
            </span>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
```

Here is the component so far, need to get a constantly updated count for the showing X of total number of options

[image: image of WIP]

Here is a [codepen of something similar](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-86xz3?file=/demo.js) pulled from Material UI example docs for a better example of the starting set of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward using the `useAutocomplete` hook since it exposes the `groupedOptions` variable (which is the [filtered options](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js#L898)).

Here's an example:

```
export default function UseAutocomplete() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputLabelProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: "use-autocomplete-demo",
    options: top100Films,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <label className={classes.label} {...getInputLabelProps()}>
          useAutocomplete
        </label>
        <input className={classes.input} {...getInputProps()} />
      </div>
      {groupedOptions.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <div>
            Showing {groupedOptions.length} of {top100Films.length}
          </div>
          <ul className={classes.listbox} {...getListboxProps()}>
            {groupedOptions.map((option, index) => (
              <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}>{option.title}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit useAutocomplete hook]

---

`groupedOptions` is not exposed in any straightforward way by the `Autocomplete` component, but it is possible to determine the number of displayed options by inspecting the HTML to count the options after it renders. The example below does this by overriding the [Paper component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L476). The options are displayed within the `Paper` element and all the options receive a [data-option-index attribute](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js#L1004). The example below uses these aspects to count the options using `querySelectorAll` from the `Paper` element:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const NumResultsHeader = ({ children, ...other }) => {
  const headerRef = React.useRef();
  const countRef = React.useRef();
  const paperRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const numOptions = paperRef.current.querySelectorAll(
      "li[data-option-index]"
    ).length;
    countRef.current.innerHTML = numOptions;
    if (numOptions > 0) {
      headerRef.current.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      headerRef.current.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={headerRef} style={{ display: "none" }}>
        Showing <span ref={countRef}></span> of {top100Films.length}
      </div>
      <Paper {...other} ref={paperRef}>
        {children}
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
};
export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      PaperComponent={NumResultsHeader}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Autocomplete show number of filtered options]

Comment: this is an awesome solution and wonderfully in depth explanation of how to accomplish! thank you Ryan :)

Comment: how can I access the top100Films/number of options to show in the `<span>Showing {countRef} of {top100Films.length}</span>` if the array of top100Films is not defined in the same file where we create the `NumResultsHeader`? I've tried passing in but am having length = undefined come up

Comment: @user10782250 I recommend that you create a new question with a code sandbox reproducing the problem you're having.

Comment: Ah, thanks! here is a codesandbox of the problem that comes with separating the options array from the `ComboBox` file/components. In the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-show-number-of-filtered-options-forked-1hurm?file=/src/ComboBox.js, im importing ComboBox into my `App.js` file and passing in options via props.

Comment: @user10782250 There isn't currently any good way to handle this, but I've logged an issue about it: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/23043. I think it is likely that v5 will support this in some fashion, but that is still a few months away from a stable release.