# Render buttons under MUI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to put buttons ("Accept" and "Cancel") under MUI Autocomplete element and am trying to implement the following

1. Autocomplete popover height is limited (say to 3 elements).

*This is done by passing `sx` to `ListboxProps`*

2. The buttons are always visible, that is, when the popover is open, the buttons are shown under the popover.

I was trying various options to put the buttons within Autocomplete (in Paper, Popper, etc.), but with little luck.

Here is the simplified code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Autocomplete } from "@mui/lab";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Paper sx={{ padding: 1 }}>
        <Autocomplete
          freeSolo
          options={["one", "two", "three", "four"]}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          ListboxProps={{ sx: { height: 100 } }}
        />
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", direction: "row" }}>
          <Chip label="Accept" sx={{ margin: 1 }} />
          <Chip label="Cancel" sx={{ margin: 1 }} />
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit polished-hooks-m6tpco]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PaperComponent` prop controls the `Paper` element that surrounds the Autocomplete's list box. You can put additional content around that list box by customizing that `Paper` component. The example below uses your original code for displaying the buttons when the list box is closed and then `CustomPaper` takes care of displaying them when the list box is open. To manage the rendering of the buttons in one place,  the buttons are passed as a prop to the custom Paper. In order for the buttons in `CustomPaper` to be clickable, you need to call `event.preventDefault()` in the `onMouseDown` event; this prevents the blur event of the text input from occurring which would then trigger the closing of the list box. This same approach is used within `Autocomplete` [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L658) and [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-base/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js#L1014).

```
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";

function CustomPaper({ children, buttons, ...other }) {
  return (
    <Paper {...other}>
      {children}
      {buttons}
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const buttons = (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", direction: "row" }}>
      <Chip
        label="Accept"
        sx={{ margin: 1 }}
        onMouseDown={(event) => {
          // Prevent input blur which triggers closing the Popper
          event.preventDefault();
        }}
        onClick={() => console.log("Accept clicked")}
      />
      <Chip
        label="Cancel"
        sx={{ margin: 1 }}
        onMouseDown={(event) => {
          // Prevent input blur which triggers closing the Popper
          event.preventDefault();
        }}
        onClick={() => console.log("Cancel clicked")}
      />
    </Box>
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Paper sx={{ padding: 1 }}>
        <Autocomplete
          freeSolo
          options={["one", "two", "three", "four"]}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          ListboxProps={{ sx: { maxHeight: 100 } }}
          PaperComponent={CustomPaper}
          componentsProps={{ paper: { buttons: buttons } }}
        />
        {buttons}
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Custom Paper component]

Related answers:

- [Display number of matching search options on Textfield input in Material UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000111/display-number-of-matching-search-options-on-textfield-input-in-material-ui-auto/64001279#64001279)
- [How to change styles of Material-UI Autocomplete list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594965/how-to-change-styles-of-material-ui-autocomplete-list/65599525#65599525)

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. The only issue is that the buttons are only visible when the popup is shown. I need another set of buttons when its closed. Not a huge deal, but want to see if  a simpler solution is possible...

Comment: @GRZa I've added another example showing how to define the buttons in one place. There isn't any practical way to avoid rendering the buttons in two different places.

Comment: thanks. The only problem is that the buttons on the popover are not responsive. The popover closes when the buttons are clicked (preventDefault/stopPropagation does not seem to help)

Comment: What should happen when they are clicked? What’s their purpose?

Comment: Execute some function… e.g. onClick={()=>console.log(“clicked”)}

Comment: @GRZa See the updated example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate getting it to the final phase.